# Flutter Exception while running

Tags: flutter, macos, exception, permission-denied

I changed the platform of my Flutter project from windows to mac, but I get the following exception when running;

Exception: The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

Can anybody help?

Comment: i think this issue is with the sdk, u need to change the SDK location in android studio in MAC .